# Share Image on facebook giving me error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook

I have script code as:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '878892922141778',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.1'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));




</script> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
   function publishOnFacebook() {
   FB.ui(
   {
   method: 'feed',
   name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
   link: 'https://apps.facebook.com/878892922141778',

   caption: 'Reference Documentation',
   description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
   },
   function(response) {
   if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
}
</script>
```

And button for share as:

```
<a hre="#" onclick="publishOnFacebook();" data-share="fb"><span class="fb-icon"></span></a>
```

But when i click on share button, its giving me error:

```
API Error Code: 191 API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

What can be the mistake?

My app details are:

[image]

When I add :

```
<a href="javascript:void(o);"
                             onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href),'facebook-share-dialog', 'width=626,height=436'); 
                                return false;">
              SHARE

            </a>
```

It shares whole page. But i just want to share specific image only.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share picture also then you can use that code in FB.ui method

```
picture: 'https://apps.facebook.com/test.png'     // your image path
```

I hope this may help you.